# Is the alien right?

Tags: lateral-thinking

Last night, I was walking down the street then I got teleported in some kind of alien vessel.

Some little alien showed up and told me :

> KDJUHW IJHIOUQ CCW IIIIIJJJ !

Then I responded :

> QOOCP, KPOW:: OKOKPPO?

So he teleported me back, and I was thinking about what he said, which I don't even understand, I don't understand what I said neither !

Do you agree with the alien? Do you think that what he said makes any sense?

Comment: Are you sure the tag lateral-thinking applies here?

Comment: It does, that's actually a hint

Comment: On the subject of tags, does this need the cipher tag?

Comment: I'm not fully familiar with all available tags, but as far as I know, I've put the correct one :)

Comment: @F1Krazy I'm not an especially talented puzzler, but I doubt that a cipher would decode "IIIIIJJJ" in any meaningful way ;)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The alien said:

> Sorry, I'm afraid I mistook you with someone else and we teleported you by mistake.

And you answered

> ... gibberish, obviously
>  This confirmed the alien's suspicions. That's why they teleported you back.

Comment: I speak alien fluently you know... :)

Comment: Hmmm.  Just mashing the keyboard isn't much of a puzzle....

Comment: @toto Thanks. I could have hardly figured it out: on my keyboard, the exclamation mark is at the exact opposite side of yours

Answer (score 1):

Did the alien say

> **what i said neither!** from here "I don't understand *what I said neither !*   I am just looking at the the structure ....four words and a exclamation mark"
>
>  the alien did not make sense as you have no idea what he is talking about.
>
>  you obviously responded with gibberish.